# Flutter AlertDialog Navigator pop black screen issue

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a strange problem with AlertDialog in flutter to dismiss the dialog. I was using the below code snippet to close the dialog as mentioned in the flutter documentation.

```
 Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
```

But show how it doesn`t work and make the app into the inactive mode and turns into the black screen window. To make it work again, i have to kill the app and restart again.

Here is the complete code for alertdialog in flutter

```
Future<Null> _showDialogContactDial(context, Contact contactRecord) async {

  return showDialog<Null>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
      return new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Confirm Number'),
        content: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextFormField(
                maxLines: 1,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Number'),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                autofocus: false,
                initialValue: contactRecord.phoneNumber.number,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text(
              'Call',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();


              _launchURL(
                  context);
            },
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: new Text('Close', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

I also noticed that it works for one button "call" without any issues but not for the cancel alert dialog as you see in the same code snippet in both button actions.

[image: dialog]
[image: after the dialogdismiss]
[image: app]
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Added screenshots for reference

Comment: The issue here is not AlertDialogBox - It has to do with your Parent widget from where it is called. your Code Works Fine. Both for Call & Close Action Widgets.

Answer (score 16):

Just add `rootNavigator:true`

```
Navigator.of(dialogcon, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for that, please?

Comment: this must be the accepted answer .. you saved my day bro!.. many thanks.. but can you please explain to us why we must add this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, save a lot time

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my application , i have made little changes in your code ,hope this might help , if this doesn't help you then I think here is a problem in _launchURl method.

```
void _showDialogContactDial(BuildContext context, Contact contactRecord){

showDialog<Null>(
context: context,
barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!
builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
  return new AlertDialog(
    title: new Text('Confirm Number'),
    content: new SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new ListBody(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextFormField(
            maxLines: 1,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Number'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            autofocus: false,
            initialValue: contactRecord.phoneNumber.number,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new FlatButton(
        child: new Text(
          'Call',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();


          _launchURL(
              context);
        },
      ),
      new FlatButton(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: new Text('Close', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
},
```

);
}

Use this method as a callback for onTap or wherever you are using it.

Comment: it is alertdialog context if you see it. I tried with Navigator.pop() but i had the same issue.

Comment: Can you post the full code ? and is there any issue in the console (stacktrace)?, please kindly post that too .

Comment: Can you check now? I have updated the complete code for dialog

Comment: It looks like the same code for me. Yeah, I removed _launchURL method. But it doesn`t work.

Comment: you tried removing Future return type and async from your method/function ?

Comment: It requires Future return otherwise it will be the asynchronous result. I don`t think that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your dialog. Surround your flatbuttons with Builder.

```
Builder(
          builder: (context) => FlatButton(
            child: Text('Cancelar'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ),
```